# Snapping mouse cursor to a line in a Delphi custom control

Tags: delphi, drawing, custom-controls, mouse, mouse-cursor

I'm wondering how can I achieve horizontal (or vertical) snapping the mouse cursor to a line. For example, on the Facebook timeline feature, when you hover the mouse over the line down the center, it snaps the cursor to the center. Bringing the mouse close to the line snaps it too.

I'd like to wrap this inside of a single custom control, rather than controls of a form. There will be either a vertical or horizontal line, and it must snap the mouse cursor to it when it gets anywhere close. I will be adding events which return the position of the line which was clicked. This control will also have a scrollbar, either vertical or horizontal, parallel to this line, and both scrollbars will never show at the same time. There's a master property whether to display this line *vertical* or *horizontal*.

The mouse should not actually move position, but just the display of the cursor should somehow be tweaked to *show* it in the center of this line, while the actual X (or Y) position never changes. I don't want to *move* the cursor, I want to *display* the cursor in the center of this line if it gets anywhere close. While the cursor is in this snapped position, it will display another custom cursor instead of the standard (or default) arrow.

All I need to know is how to handle, within this control, the event of a mouse pointer coming in the vicinity of this line and tweak the display of the cursor to be in the center of this line.

Comment: As dumb as it sounds, just in case anyone wants to go ahead and build a control shell for me to demonstrate this, please let me know in advance so that I know to wait for it. Otherwise, I'm still open to any suggestions on how to handle this.

Comment: I didn't down vote you but I'm confused by this question. The title says "snapping mouse cursor" but the text says "the mouse should not actually move position, but the display of the cursor should be tweaked". What do you mean the cursor should not move but it should move? Am I the only one who finds this paradoxical?  I just had a look on Facebook timeline, and I don't get it.  Picture?

Comment: @WarrenP The X,Y positions (where the user is pointing mouse) never changes, but the view of where the cursor is shown is changed. So for examle you can be pointing it at 60,100 but it displays at 55,100, and pointing it at 50,100 also displays it at 55,100.

Comment: You could say I'm trying to *lie* to the GUI about where the user is actually pointing the mouse and alter where this `+` shows, while not touching the actual mouse coordinates. Adding to my previous comment - there would be a range of sensitivity on the X axis between 50 and 60 - if the user is pointing anywhere in that range, it *looks* like they're pointing it at 55.

Comment: Another example - on the FB timeline - slowly move the mouse from left to right towards the center line. When it gets close, it jumps the focus to the line. keep slowly moving horizontally and it doesn't appear to move - until you've moved the mouse a good distance to the right side of the line - which then the pointer jumps back over to the right where it belongs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Snapping requires you to snap *something*.

- in AutoCAD the "cursor" is actually a horizontal and vertical line intersecting where the "cursor" is
- Photoshop uses the Windows mouse, but snaps the *effect* to guidelines
- Facebook snaps a little **+** sign to a spot on the timeline

You need to track the mouse's position (i.e. `OnMouseMove`) and if the cursor is "close enough" you can then decide what to do.

Here's a little sample program where i have an imaginary vertical line at 150px from the left. If i get close enough to that line, a little Facebook **+** appears:

[image]

```
const
    centerLine = 150; //"line" is at 150px from the left
    tolerance = 15; //15px on either size is about good.

procedure TForm1.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
    if IsMouseNearLine(x, y) then
    begin
        //We're on the centerline-ish. React by...
        //...changing the cursor to a <->
        Self.Cursor := crSizeWE;

        //and maybe let's put a "+" there, like Facebook
        if (FPlusLabel = nil) then
        begin
            FPlusLabel := TLabel.Create(Self);
            FPlusLabel.Parent := Self;
            FPlusLabel.Caption := '+';
            FPlusLabel.Alignment := taCenter;
            FPlusLabel.Font.Color := $00996600; //Windows UX "Main Instruction" color
            FPlusLabel.Font.Style := FPlusLabel.Font.Style + [fsBold];
        end;

        FPlusLabel.Left := centerLine-(FPlusLabel.Width div 2);
        FPlusLabel.Top := Y-(FPlusLabel.Height div 2);
        FPlusLabel.Visible := True;
    end
    else
    begin
        Self.Cursor := crDefault;
        if Assigned(FPlusLabel) then
            FPlusLabel.Visible := False;
    end;
end;

function TForm1.IsMouseNearLine(X, Y: Integer): Boolean;
begin
    if (x >= (centerLine-tolerance)) and (x <= (centerLine+tolerance)) then
    begin
        //we're close-ish to the line
        Result := true;
    end
    else
        Result := False;
end;
```

Things start to get hairy when you have other controls, each needing to play along with the `MouseMove` messages. But it's not *too* bad if you forward them all to a single handler; performing client-to-screen-to-formClient before you do.

> **Note**: Any code is released into the public domain. No attribution required.

Comment: Thanks, except I'm asking for wrapping it inside its own custom control (requires a completely different approach) and also I need more help with how to display the cursor than to identify where it is. Also, I see you creating `FPlusLabel` but I don't see where it is free'd...

Comment: Your child control is going to need the help of form it's sitting on. It's not going to get `MouseMove` or `Click` events when the mouse isn't actually over the form. You don't need to free `FPlusLabel`; it is freed when it's *owner* is freed. (`FPlusLabel := TLabel.Create(theOwner);`). Or you could chalk it up to sample code, that omits as much as possible in order to keep the answer clear as possible. The the label's text color also doesn't honor the user's color preferences.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach I can see is to make a TPaintBox control with its own Cursor property, so you hide the built in windows cursor, and you owner draw the "+" symbol at its "snapped" location.

The mouse pointer is never really moved, but it is "replaced" by the owner-drawn cursor image when the real mouse pointer is inside the control bounds of the TPaintBox.